# Nvidia driver causing flickering in menu?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, nvidia, animations

Like many Ubuntu users I'm using Compiz Desktop Effects with Gnome. However since Ubuntu 10.10 I've noticed that the zoom effect on my drop down menus i.e. The gnome menu bar have a flicking thin white border when they are opened. It appears very briefly and flickers each time a drop down menu is opened.

I can't remember this happening on Ubuntu 10.04 and it doesn't seem to be theme specific, as I tried it on Ambiance and Radiance and still see the flicking white border.

I'm using the nvidia-current proprietary driver enabled through Additional Drivers menu.

Thanks for any help on the matter!

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure "Sync to vblank" is checked in "OpenGL Settings" in `nvidia-settings`
- In CompizConfig Settings Manager, make sure your actual refresh rate is set in "General Options > Display Settings > Refresh Rate", "Sync to vblank" is checked, and "Detect Refresh Rate" is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks, I've carried out the changes you have stated, do I need to restart X?

Comment: Actually, I just restarted my machine after the changes, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: You need to save the changes in nvidia-settings to the xorg.conf file ("apply" is only temporary).

Comment: Well I've tried the above and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try setting another effect in the "Animations" plugin and see if it has the same problem.

Comment: Well I was using the zoom animation, which had the flicking border, but some others don't like, fade, but others do like Dream or sidekick. Guess it's how fancy and flashy they are really.